# Create microsoft teams announcement via SMTP

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp, microsoft-teams

I am using `JavaMailSender` class to add new messages to Microsoft Teams channel via SMTP protocol. It works fine but I need to create announcement not default conversation message. Is there any way to implement that?

I am using spring framework and JavaMailSenderImpl class to send message to teams. Maybe I should add some headers or smth like that to send announcement, not the conversation message?

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class DefaultTeamsService implements TeamsService{
    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Value("${app.mail.from}")
    private String from;

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String to, String subject, String html) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = formMessage(from, to, subject, html);
            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.error("Failed to form message", e);
        }
    }

    private MimeMessage formMessage(String from, String to, String subject, String html) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        message.setSubject("", "utf-8");

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");

        helper.setFrom(from);
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setText(html, true);

        return message;
    }
```

[This is how it shows now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivJad.png)

[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YUR3.png)

Comment: what do you mean about "Announcement" exactly? Like with a title, etc?

Comment: When adding new message in teams channel you can specify it's type: "New conversation" and "Announcement". [Example](https://imgur.com/a/oVWLI4a)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to create an actual "announcement" type directly like this, or if it's even possible, but there's a good the limited markdown syntax is supported at least, so there are some "Heading" and other formatting options that could be of use - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772) for more. Another alternative is to look at using [webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook). Creating a Bot and using proactive messaging and Adaptive cards is another option, but a lot more work.

Comment: Hi @BANTYC, Can you please confirm if the above solution works for you?